# Saving an indexed, empty Pandas data frame to excel throws out of bounds error

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a data frame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c']).set_index(['a',  'b'], sort=True)
```

which therefore, doesn't have any data.

And I am trying to write that to an excel file this way:

```
Writer = pd.ExcelWriter(OutputBaseDir + EnvPrefix + '{}_topup.xlsx'.format(ProcessingCompartment), engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(Writer, sheet_name='topup')

Writer.save()
```

which throws this error

`index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried df.to_excel ?

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because in your code you are creating an array with a size 0 first axis.

Check your df shape, looks like `(0, 1)`

Comment: Yeah I know it is a size 0 0-axis but then pandas should not access index 0 right? Even if it is. How do I add a row with nulls just in case?

Comment: you can add null values like, `pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, 0, values=["null"], axis=0))`